# Can't change AllowOverwrite data streamer option for .NET apache ignite thin client

Tags: c#, .net-core, ignite, thin-client

I try to remove some data using the thin client data streamer (.NET apache ignite) but i end up with an exception:

> DataStreamer can't remove data when AllowOverwrite is false.

My problem is when i try to change AllowOverwrite to true it is not respected.

```
using Apache.Ignite.Core;
using Apache.Ignite.Core.Client;

IgniteClientConfiguration _configuration = new()
{
    Endpoints = new[] { "127.0.0.1:10800" }
};

using (var client = Ignition.StartClient(_configuration))
{
    var cache = client.GetOrCreateCache<int, string>("myCache");
    using (var dataStreamer = client.GetDataStreamer<int, string>("myCache"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"AllowOverwrite default value: {dataStreamer.Options.AllowOverwrite}");

        // Set AllowOverwrite to true
        dataStreamer.Options.AllowOverwrite = true;
        Console.WriteLine($"AllowOverwrite: {dataStreamer.Options.AllowOverwrite}"); // Set not repected

        dataStreamer.Remove(1);
    }
}

/*
    Results in:
    AllowOverwrite default value: False
    AllowOverwrite: False
    Unhandled exception. Apache.Ignite.Core.Client.IgniteClientException: DataStreamer 
    can't remove data when AllowOverwrite is false.
       at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.Datastream.DataStreamerClient`2.Remove(TK key)
*/
```

Notes:

- It works as expected if i use the thick client instead of the thin client (but that's not desirable in my case).
- I couldn't find any related config to enable this option when starting the server node/s

Any advice as to what I am missing here?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying a data streamer after it was created, which is not supported. After the instance is created, you can obtain only a copy of its configuration. Provide the complete configuration on initialization instead:

```
var options = new DataStreamerClientOptions {AllowOverwrite = false};
    
using (var streamer = Client.GetDataStreamer<int, object>(cache.Name, options))
{
    ...
}
```

> I couldn't find any related config to enable this option when starting
> the server node/s

It's not server configuration, it's only about data steaming.